# Enabling Kubernetes PodPresets with kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I've got a kubernetes cluster which was set up with kops with 1.5, and then upgraded to 1.6.2. I'm trying to use PodPresets. The docs state the following requirements:

> 1. You have enabled the api type settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset
> 2. You have enabled the admission controller PodPreset
> 3. You have defined your pod presets

I'm seeing that for 1.6.x, the first is taken care of (how can I verify?). How can I apply the second? I can see that there are three kube-apiserver-* pods running in the cluster (I imagine it's for the 3 azs). I guess I can edit their yaml config from kubernetes dashboard and add PodPreset to the admission-control string. But is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list the API groups which are currently enabled in your cluster either with the `api-versions` kubectl command, or by sending a GET request to the `/apis` endpoint of your `kube-apiserver`:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/apis
{
  "paths": [
  "/api",
  "/api/v1",
  "...",
  "/apis/settings.k8s.io",
  "/apis/settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1",
  "...",
}
```

> **Note**: The `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1` API is enabled by default on Kubernetes v1.6 and v1.7 but will be [disabled by default in v1.8](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/47690).

You can use a kops [ClusterSpec](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_spec.md) to customize the configuration of your Kubernetes components during the cluster provisioning, including the API servers.

This is described on the documentation page [Using A Manifest to Manage kops Clusters](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/manifests_and_customizing_via_api.md#exporting-a-cluster), and the full spec for the KubeAPIServerConfig type is available [in the kops GoDoc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kops/pkg/apis/kops#KubeAPIServerConfig).

Example:

```
apiVersion: kops/v1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: k8s.example.com
spec:
  kubeAPIServer:
    AdmissionControl:
      - NamespaceLifecycle
      - LimitRanger
      - PodPreset
```

To update an existing cluster, perform the following steps:

1. Get the full cluster configuration with

   ```
   kops get cluster name --full
   ```
2. Copy the kubeAPIServer spec block from it.
3. **Do not push back the full configuration**. Instead, edit the cluster configuration with

   ```
   kops edit cluster name
   ```
4. Paste the kubeAPIServer spec block, add the missing bits, and save.
5. Update the cluster resources with

   ```
   kops update cluster nane
   ```
6. Perform a rolling update to apply the changes:

   ```
   kops rolling-update name
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I just did a kops edit cluster. The spec doesn't currently have a section for kubeAPIServer. Is it safe to add one with just AdmissionControl.PodPreset, or should I explicitly specify all the current settings for AdmissionControl adding in PodPreset? Once added, I imagine a kops update cluster > Rolling Update should work?

Comment: Does the output of `kops get cluster $NAME --full -o yaml` contain spec.kubeAPIServer? If yes you might save a copy locally, update it, and perform a `kops rolling-update`.

Comment: Shows me this:

kubeAPIServer:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    admissionControl:
    - NamespaceLifecycle
    - LimitRanger
    - ServiceAccount
    - PersistentVolumeLabel
    - DefaultStorageClass
    - DefaultTolerationSeconds
    - ResourceQuota

If I save a copy locally and edit it, how would I apply it to the cluster? kops update cluster doesn't show these options.